# Do contact forces form a field/wave?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, material-science, contact-mechanics

Non-contact forces like gravitational forces exist between two objects in any medium because of the establishment of a field/wave.

Since at an atomic level, 'physical' contact won't really be possible for *any* kind of force (contact or non-contact) , so is a 'field' established here as well? (albeit extremely small)

Also, if I consider gravity at this atomic/molecular level between two objects, is a gravitational field still formed? And as for contact force like friction, is friction forming a wave? At this level, friction, too, can be considered 'non-contact', right?

Answer (score 0):

Contact forces are not really real, they are just the result of other forces, almost always the electric force.

That means while there is no "contact force field" like there is a "gravitational field" or "electric field," but contact forces are the result of complicated interactions of electric fields.

Comment: I see. What about the existence of gravitational force/field existing at an atomic level?